# How to call a function once the api call finishes fetching the data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling a service in `ngOnInit()` and assigning the data to a variable once it returns data.

```js
let sampleData = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000];
if (this.job.currency !== 'USD') {
      this.jobService.getFxRate('USD', 'INR')
        .subscribe((fxRate) => {
          this.fxrate =  fxRate;
        });
}
```

In html table I am calling a method which uses that variable to perform operaions

```js
myfunction(index) {

   if(this.job.currency !== 'USD') {
      return  sampleData[index] / this.fxRate;
   } 
   else
   {
    return  sampleData[index];
   }
    
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];let i = index"> {{ myfunction(i) }} </div>
```

But `console.log` is logging undefined for first few logs till service returns data. I want to call `myfunction()` once `this.fxRate` is defined.
How can I do that?

Comment: This will always return undefined because your `myfunction()` does not have any parameter I think it should be `myfunction(i){return  sampleData[i] / this.fxRate;}`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I missed to add it. Thats not the issue.

Comment: @NareshShetty, Use `Observable` instead of simple variable;

Comment: @NareshShetty Try posted code!

Answer (score 0):

Initial value of `this.fxrate` is **`undefined`** so, you are getting `undefined` in the `console`.

you can call your function once you get the data in the **subscription**

```
 if (this.job.currency !== 'USD') {
      this.jobService.getFxRate('USD', 'INR')
        .subscribe((fxRate) => {
          this.fxrate =  fxRate;
          this.myfunction();
        });
    }
```

change your function something like below

```
myfunction() {
   if(this.fxrate) {
     console.log(this.fxrate);
     // do something ....
   } 
 }
```

you can set it with the use of **`*ngIf`**

It will execute your function once the data is available  in your **`this.fxrate`** variable

```
<div *ngIf="fxrate">
   <div *ngFor="let item of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];let i = index"> {{ myfunction(i) }} 
 </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: See service call. If currency is in ''USD' then also this.fxRate will be undefined.

Comment: I am printing the data returned from myFunction() in html based on index value. I have updated the question. Hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

> But console.log is logging undefined for first few logs till service returns data. I want to call myfunction() once this.fxRate is defined. How can I do that?

You can do it by checking `this.fxrate` `is defined` and  calling function inside of subscription:

```
if (this.job.currency !== 'USD') {
  this.jobService.getFxRate('USD', 'INR')
    .subscribe((fxRate) => {
      this.fxrate = fxRate;
      if(this.fxrate) {
        this.myfunction();
      }
    });
}
```

If you're using fetched data only in html template, you can use [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) for that. It subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted:

```
if (this.job.currency !== 'USD') {
  this.fxrat = this.jobService.getFxRate('USD', 'INR');
}

<div *ngFor="let item of fxrate | async; let i = index"></div>
```

Comment: I am returning value from that function. Which i have to display in html. I have updated the question. Hope it makes sense now

Comment: @NareshShetty you can use async pipe for that. It subscribes and unsubscribe to your `Observable`

Comment: Can you share **documentation**

Comment: @NareshShetty  here is a good [explanation](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794), [Angular docs - async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Answer (score 0):

Try below HTML code:

```
<span *ngIf="fxRate">
  <div *ngFor="let item of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];let i = index">
    {{ myfunction(i) }} 
  </div>
</span>
```

[StackBlitz Without Service Call](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twjgpx)

Comment: I am calling service when currency is **non USD** as you can see in code snippet. If its **USD** fxRate  will be undefined.

Comment: Ok then you have write `else` block and assign a default value

Comment: Or you can provide a stackblitz so I can try with your data itself!

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function in Template is not a good approach. You can also do this following way

```
    let sampleData = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]; 
    if (this.job.currency !== 'USD') { 
    this.jobService.getFxRate('USD', 'INR') .subscribe((fxRate) => { 
        this.fxrate = fxRate;
        this.items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(index => sampleData[index] / this.fxRate)
      });
 }
```

And in Template

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of items"> {{ item }} </div>
```